# MIT Hashing Lecture Explanation

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hash

In MIT, Lec 7 Introduction to Algorithms video (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JZHBa-rLrBA) 
How does he find 1.A to be 5.5? (at 47th min)
Thank you if you took the time to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that 1011001 treated as a fraction is right shifted by (w - r). w is 7 because the computer has 7-bit words. and r is 3 because m = 8 = 2^3 - 2^r. So you need to right shift A by (w - r) = 7 - 3 = 4. So you can treat 1011001 as if it were actually 101 PERIOD 1001 where 101 is the integral part and 1001 is the fractional part. The integral part comes out to 5. The fractional part comes out to a bit more than .5. So that adds up to 5.5. Hope that helps.